# Java private constructors visibility

Tags: java, constructor, private

I try to understand why there is a difference between accessibility of class members when speaking about constructors.

Consider the following example:

```
class A {
  static class B {  
    private B(String s) {}
    private void foo() {}
  }
  static class C extends B {
    public C(String s) {
      super(s); // call B(String), which is private, and obviously accessible
    }
    void bar() {
      foo(); // compilation error (symbol unknown), as B.foo() is private
    }
  }
}
```

Private members of `A`, as being private, should not be accessible from `B`. For fields and methods, it is the case, but it seems that constructors are not following the same rule.

From the JLS-8 ([6.6.1. Determining Accessibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1)), we can read:

> [...]
>
> A member (class, interface, field, or method) of a reference type, or a constructor of a class type, is accessible only if the type is accessible and the member or constructor is declared to permit access:
>
> - [...]
> - Otherwise, the member or constructor is declared `private`, and access is permitted if and only if it occurs within the body of the top level class (§7.6) that encloses the declaration of the member or constructor.

Can anyone explain me why the constructor is accessible from `C`, even while being declared `private`?

Comment: Just because you can call super doesn't mean the constructor is accessible

Comment: Can anyone explain me why the constructor is accessible from C, even while being declared private? -> Because both B and C are inner classes of A. Won't work anymore if you move B and C outside A.

Comment: @JörnBuitink: If that's the case, then why is `foo()` *not* accessible? There does appear to be an inconsistency here.

Comment: @michaelsnowden calling `super` is accessing the constructor; therefore it _is_ accessible.

Comment: Note that `super.foo()` works.

Comment: @JonSkeet If you make `foo` static, it is accessible. A constructor is sort of like a static method. Eh, that's the best I can do.

Comment: @michaelsnowden: I don't see any explanation for that in the spec though...

Comment: @daiscog Yeah. I'm sorry--it was unclear what I meant. I meant to make the distinction between calling `super` and calling `new B("")` from within `C`. I hadn't yet tested myself that both of them work.

Comment: I think it's worth noting that this has nothing to do with the fact that `C` extends `B`. For example, this works: `class A {
    static class B {
        static void foo() {}
    }
    static class C {
        void bar() {
            new B();
            B.foo();
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: @Arun That's C#. Not Java. Static classes can have constructors in Java.

Comment: @Arun this is Java, not C#.  A static class in C# cannot be instantiated.  It can in Java as it means something different (a static **inner** class is not linked to an instance of its outer class).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The method `foo()` is private, so you don't inherit it and can't call it directly from the `C` class.

However, you can see private methods and constructor from `B` since everything is declared in the same containing class, and access them with `super`, which is why `super()` works.
In the same way, you can access `foo` with `super.foo()`.

Note that you can redefine a new foo method in `C`, but this method will not override `B.foo()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers WilQu & @benzonico. It's seems to be the trick. I consequently accept your answer.

Answer (score 3):

So the trick here might be the following :

you cannot access `foo` because it is declared private so you don't inherit it in C.

However, as was noted in comments you can access `super.foo();` because  `super` refers to a type that is declared in the same top level class (see JLS 6.6.1 for this).

Then the trick is that calling `super(s)` can be viewed as calling `super.<init>(s)` which ends up being the same case as `super.foo()`

Answer (score -2):

Foo() method is not accessible in class C, as foo() method is private and private method can not be inherited to base class.

For constructors, CONSTRUCTORS NEVER EVER BE INHERITED. Also, I compiled this code :

```
 class Vehicle{  
        int speed=50;  
        private Vehicle()
        {
           System.out.println("Private Vehicle constructor");
        }
    } 
    public class Bike4 extends Vehicle{  
        int speed=100;   
    Bike4()
    {
        super();
         System.out.println("Hi I n constructor");
    }
  void display(){  
   System.out.println(super.speed);//will print speed of Vehicle now  
  }  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
   Bike4 b=new Bike4();  
   b.display();  

}  
}
```

And get Compile time Error : Vehicle() has private access in Vehicle
        super();
        ^
Which clearly indicates that a private constructor cannot be accessed using super. If we are able to initialize or access a private constructor, then what's the point in creating a private constructor.

Comment: Please see other answers, yours is not really relevant to the question.